# How and when to use AppRouter and Controllers?

Tags: javascript, marionette

I'm struggling to get my head around the appropriate use of a controller within a Marionette application. I understand now that AppRouter and Controller go hand in hand.

I have a general/dashboard style view in my application that summarizes lots of different datasets. You're able to view these datasets in more detail by selecting them on the dashboard. For example there's a list of 'tasks' which allows you to select one for more details.

The way I imagine this working is by having various 'routes' for each of the detailed views leading out from the dashboard like '/tasks/:taskId'. Clicking on an item will take you out to one of these routes that's managed by an AppRouter/Controller pair.

Would you then have an over-arching controller/application style object that manages the dashboard? and how might it draw out the various list views for the data it's summarizing?

At present I have such a controller called 'DashboardController' that instantiates the collections and CollectionView it needs. Moving into a detailed view I either make a call to the api through a surrogate model for a specific record or pass the collection around globally.

```
var DashboardController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize : function () {
      this._taskData = new TasksCollection();

      // Layout will make a call to 'fetch' on each collection passed in once rendered.
      this.layout = new DashboardLayout({
        tasks : this._taskData
      });
    },

    // This method is mapped to from DashBoardRouter
    main : function () {
      this.layout.render();
    }
});
```

My concern and cause for confusion here is that I am not entirely confident how I should be using AppRouter/Controller to separate concerns when in this example they clearly are easily conflicted. Should the task collection sit in one place and be the property of a controller?

The options seem limited:

Compose such controllers from other controllers (So DashboardController calls into TaskController for a list view).

Completely re-think what Controllers represent. This is tricky because AppRouter seems to be a dogmatic attempt to bind routes (tokenized state) to controller methods.

There are a few questions in here but I guess the ultimate question is how you can present/compose views from multiple data sources without crossing concerns?

Comment: This is probably a bit opinion based, but as far as you concern about who should "own" the TasksCollection, why not just make it a singleton? Are you ever going to have more than one instance of your TasksCollection class? If not, then just make a single instance of it available to the rest of your app, either via marionette's module system, requirejs, browserify, global app object or whatever other dependency-handling system you've opted to use.

Comment: My practice is to have one Controller at the application level, and then break out functionality into modules each will have their own controller. This way the modules don't have to know about each other. Example app: https://github.com/cbroome/marionette_example